# Temporary tables in sp

Tags: sql

I just joined an IT company. I have been seeing that development team have been using Temp tables in procedures. I know what are temp tables. Can anyone just give me one small example showing the data moving from temp table to actual table(For insert) in the end of procedure.

Comment: From a syntax point of view, there is no difference between regular tables and temp tables.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the table structure is identical, this should work fine:

```
INSERT INTO RealTable
SELECT * FROM #TemporaryTable
```

Comment: Tobber - Any updations or insertions should be done on temp table before updating in real tables right. And both the table structure should be identical right.

Comment: That depends on your needs, unless you actually need temporary tables, you should just update and insert into the real tables immediately.